# Best way to determine the type of an object at runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, rtti

So what I am trying to do is implementing the message pattern. And as far as I understand, the user will act upon what message type I put in, not the message type doing the action. Therefore, this is how I approach it:

I want to get the datatype of the object so I can do a switch statement but I am not so sure where to start.

I have looked through google and do some research but none is successful. This is what I have tried:

- Decltype : not even close to what I want
- typeof : I am not so clear about how to use
- dynamic-cast : not close to what I want

Basically, what I want to have at the end is something like this:

```
switch (typeof(a)) {
    class_a : //do something
    class_b : //do something
}
```

An if statement would work the same for me. Can anyone help me out? I would prefer using standard library.

Comment: See `boost::variant`

Comment: @user1034749 is there a way to do it without using outsider lib?

Comment: this might be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @bolov I am trying to implement the message pattern. And as far as I believe, it would be based on the the object to define what message I put in and act upon that.

Comment: You can use `union` in c++11 to manage not trivial objects, but actually you write almost the same code as `boost::variant` or `boost::any`

Comment: I would second the XY problem suggestion.  This is an oddly specific question that doesn't sound like asking just for the sake of knowing (correct me if I'm wrong).  See my answer below, but if you clarify your actual problem, we can help better.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty I am still trying to understand how to implement it and for now, this is the only way I have thought of

Comment: Take a look at how functioncalls are dispatched to the according overloads in the implementation of the Visitor Pattern, as inspiration. Using a variant type is also a good idea. Lastly, check out the `typeid` operator, but be sure to read all its documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `typeof` in standard C++ (although there is a GCC extension by that name).  You are looking for the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator.  This returns a reference to a `static const` [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) instance that contains the run-time type information (RTTI) for the object.  You can compare the result to the `typeid`s of the various classes you are interested in.

As a trivial example ([see it run at ideone](https://ideone.com/dhUnd0)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B: public A {};
class C: public A {};


int main() {
    const A& a = C{};

    const auto& id = typeid(a);

    if(id == typeid(B)) {
        std::cout << "Got a B." << std::endl;
    }
    else if(id == typeid(C)) {
        std::cout << "It's a C!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Note that you can't use a `switch`, because the objects are not integers.)  This example will print `It's a C!`.

Note that in general, using RTTI shouldn't be your first response (take heed especially if you're coming from languages such as Java, where dynamic typing -- and its associated speed hit -- is taken for granted).

RTTI is comparatively slow compared to other object-oriented paradigms, even dynamic dispatch (`virtual` functions).  If you're trying to implement a Message pattern, consider passing an explicit value as a message, rather than shoehorning your other objects into the pattern and incurring the expensive overhead of RTTI.

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1. If I am insisting of this, basically I would have to store an object of the type I want to compare, right? It's not able to compare directly to the class (blueprint) itself? 2. What do you mean by passing an explicit value as a message?

Comment: You can directly pass references to the `std::type_info` structure around if you want; you don't have to instantiate an object (see where I'm doing `typeid(B)` for example).  And if I understand correctly, you are simply trying to send messages between components, and then perform different actions based on the message?  Often you can simply get away with sending an instance (explicit value) of an `enum`, which is as fast as you can get in C++.  What are you doing with the object after you take its `typeid`?

Comment: So with my current architecture, I am having 3 different types of message and 1 user. Every message have a base class as BaseMessage. And I use a factoryPattern to create a message to pass to user. And base on the type of message, I will let the user act differently. But I have just thought of a way to get away with, create a new variable in each sub-class and put an enum in it. Then the user can easily check the enum to get the type of message :D

Answer (score 0):

> dynamic-cast : not close to what I want

You are holding it wrong. Dynamic cast certainly can do what you want.

```
if (dynamic_cast<c1*>(a)) { ... }
else if (dynamic_cast<c2*>(a)) { ... }
```

The static type of `*a` must be polymorphic. The same thing works for references. It does not and can not work if you pass it by value.

This is however a dangerous and error-prone way of implementing this. If you want to implement something like N message types for M recipient types, with all M×N actions being potentially different, consider using the Visitor pattern, especially an acyclic implementation of it.

Comment: Hi. I am fully aware of this using of virtual method. As I have cited in the beginning of my post, I am trying to implement the message pattern, which ask the user to know the type of the object I pass in. So thanks :)

Comment: Removed basic suggestion, added advanced suggestion.